# Case-insensitive autocomplete in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a javascript code that is used for autocomplete functionality. It highlights the text that is entered in a search box and matches it with the text in a database. This is case-sensitive, so it only highlights the text which is in the database table. I want the search to be case-insensitive.
This is my existing code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php echo $tagsString; ?>];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
 $.extend( $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var term = this.element.val(),
            html = item.label.replace( term, "<span class='f1'>$&</span>" );
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $("<a></a>").html(html) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: assuming `$tagsString` is the data from a database call and that its the autocomplete of that data that is case insensitive, why not `toLower` that php string?

Answer (score 2):

in your database code use LOWER on both sides of the equasion.

```
... WHERE LOWER(db_field) = LOWER(:text) ...
```

Or you can cast the input to lower before giving it to the database and omit the right `LOWER` in this case

In case of LIKE

```
... WHERE LOWER(db_field) like '%' || LOWER(:text) || '%' ...
```

Please always quote properly or better use perpared statements to prevent SQL injections.

EDIT: Found a cleaner way using only bindings without quoting

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MySQL.

You can lower field name and searched value,

```
WHERE LOWER( db_table.db_field ) = LOWER(:text) // find exact match
```

or use like with lower:

```
WHERE  LOWER( db_table.db_field ) LIKE '%' || LOWER(:text) || '%'  // find all that have this text as substring
```

But in boh cases remember to use parametrized statemenets, in order to avoid SQL injection atacks.

Comment: According to this page it should http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php. I assume you are using param bindings.

Comment: No it does not. I just tested. Bindings inside a String seem not to be recognized. But I found a similar solution. '%' || :text || '%'